# Why $group is very slow in aggregation and how can faster it in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My query is taking **~3 seconds** to execute with the **$group** stage, How can I **faster this**?

```
My query is:
db.getCollection('employee_data').aggregate([
  { $match: //Filter
  },
  { 
   $group: 
   {
     _id: {
       employee_id:"$employee_id",
       activity_date:"$activity_date"
     }, 
     trips: { $sum: 1 }
   }
  }
])
Data size : 4M records
```

Comment: what is the schema and why `_id: "week"` is hard coded?

Comment: How can I take benefits of indexing in the group stage?

Comment: @krishnaPrasad Updated the question.

Comment: Are your query using index for `$match` stage? if yes than that will be optimized one. I think your query does not usage index at `$match` stage that's its very slow.

Comment: For more help, please check the official documentation of mongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes and this one also: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#aggregation-pipeline-optimization

Comment: @krishnaPrasad Yes, my query is taking benefits of indexing in match stage. but even after the filter, there is a lot of data to the group.